# How to reset or restart nested loops

Tags: c#, loops, nested

```
loop one
{
    looptwo
    {
        if(condition=true)
        {
           reset values//restart both loops
        }
     }
}
and possibilities for reset values is 3

basically i want to compair two matrices

a= 1 2 3 4

   1 2 3 4 
b= 3 4 5 6
   4 6 7 8

and when row 1 of a[] is matched with row 1 of b[].....i will add these rows and a[]
become = 2 4 6 8

for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
for(j=0;j<columns;j++)
{
a[i]=a[i]+b[i,j] 
}
```

and again find my maches from restart with new a[] Matrix

and i have to insure that all rows of b[] matrix are checked with a[] which are 3 in this case

Comment: can you be a little bit more clear about what you're trying to do?

Comment: you surely meant `if(condition==true)`, right?

Comment: Let me clarify, what do you mean with "reset values" and "posibilities for reset values is 3" ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `goto` to break out of multiple loop levels in C#.  For example:

```
RESTART:
    while (a) {
        while (b) {
            if (that_other_thing)
                goto RESTART;
        }
    }
```

Well, you don't *have* to use `goto` but the alternative might be using a bunch of flag variables to indicate that a restart is required.  And that code will probably be pretty hard to follow.

Comment: This will work fine, but I just can't help getting *shivers* when I see the `goto` keywork in action even if this is a pretty harmless variant of it.

Comment: @Øyvind: That's because you believe that `goto` is an inherently evil tool, instead of one that has appropriate uses but should not be used when more readable constructs are available. :)

Comment: That seems just about correct. Good thing I know that myself, even if I still see the small red horns on top of it ;)

Comment: @Øyvind: Yeah, I avoided it for a long time too, and in a few cases I paid for it...

Answer (score 1):

The best choice here is to move the loops into their own method, and return from inside the inner loop. Example:

```
public void MyMehod(){
  loop one{
    looptwo{
      if(condition=true){
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If this is not possible for some reason, you can use a bool value that you set in the inner loop to bail out of all of them, but this is a bit more messy:

```
bool endloop = false;
while(!endloop){
  while(!endloop){
    if(condition){
      endloop = true;
    }
  }
}
```

For a while loop it looks ok, but even more messy for a `for` loop or a `foreach` loop.

Comment: That doesn't restart the loops, it cancels them.

Comment: I thought that was what he meant when he said `reset`, but I agree that it does not cover the `restart` part. But for reset/cancel I think that is the best approach.

Comment: Having special bool value for bailing out is both less efficient and is much less expressive then the direct `goto`.

Answer (score 0):

```
            Start:
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    if(j == 5)
                        goto Start;
                }
            }
```

Although structuring your code in a way to not use a `goto` is a much better approach...

Comment: What would you propose for this case in order to avoid `goto` and not make the code ugly/hard to follow?

Comment: @Vlad Extract the 'work' out of the looping into a method of some sort which can be looped upon and called as many times as needed returning via the method or an out param the needed data. Context is key; knowing more about the problem set would be beneficial.

Comment: having to define a separate method for potentially very small code (hoping that the optimizer will inline it) is an overkill, and imho makes the code harder to understand (and maintain, too).

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that you will have a condition that will tell you that you don't need to restart, you could wrap the whole thing in one more loop.

```
bool keepLooping = true;
while (keepLooping)
{
  keepLooping = false;
  for (int x = 0; x < maxx; x++)
  {
    for (int y = 0; y < maxy; y++)
    {
      if (DoSomething(x, y))
      {
        keepLooping = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (keepLooping)
    {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

If you are checking a list for duplicates and modifying them do make all entries unique, you might do something like this (assuming string values):

```
List<string> a = GetNamesFromeSomewhere();

bool duplicateFound = true;
while (duplicateFound )
{
  duplicateFound = false;
  for (int x = 0; x < a.Length; x++)
  {
    for (int y = x + 1; y < a.Length; y++)
    {
      if (a[x].Equals(a[y]))
      {
        //Change a[y], but now we have to recheck for duplicates...
        a[y] += "_";
        duplicateFound = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (duplicateFound)
    {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use numeric loop variables like i and j you can just reset the values

e.g.

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
   for (j=0; j<10; j++) {
      if (var[i][j] == 'x') {
         i=0; j=0; break;
      }
   }
}
```

you can also use the method approach as suggested earlier

```
void someFunction(params) {
   for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
      for (j=0; j<10; j++) {
         if (var[i][j] == 'x') {
            someFunction(params)
            return;
         }
      }
   }       
}
```

Comment: p.s. you have to be careful not to end up in an infinite loop.

Comment: actually since you only break out of the `j` loop you don't have to reset `j` and `i` has to be set to `-1`. This is also very error prone